# Initialize a structure with a template

Tags: templates, syntax, struct, d

What's the correct way to initialize a structure with a template?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
struct Point3(T) if(isNumeric!T) {
        T x;
        T y;
        T z;
}

enum Blocksize = Point3!ubyte{x:32, y:32, z:32};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two distinct syntaxes:

1. Struct initializaters:

   ```
   enum Point3!ubyte Blocksize = {x:32, y:32, z:32};
   ```
2. Struct literals:

   ```
   enum Blocksize = Point3!ubyte(32, 32, 32);
   ```

Both of the above will work.

Answer (score 2):

D doesn't have named params so take those out and your code will work:

```
enum Blocksize = Point3!ubyte(32, 32, 32);
```

Just put the args in the same position list as the struct. You can also define constructors in the struct if you want to open up other options.